# List of all n integers to make a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

List of all integers n such that $1 \leqslant n\leqslant 10$ and such that there exists a field with $n$ elements.

Actually I coudn't understand how to start. Advanced thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2,3,5,7,4,8,9 are these integers The cardinal of a finite field is $p^n$ where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: how do i find the integers?

Comment: The last sentence tells you.

Comment: The cardinal of a finite field is $p^n$, $p$ a prime $2,3,5,7,2^2=4,2^3=8, 3^2=9\leq 10$.

Comment: yah now i get it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A finite field necessarily must have a cardinal equal to a power of a prime. This fundamental fact let us to answer how many finite fields are there for $1\le n\le N$ for reasonable (not too big), in particular for $N=10$.